# How to include jquery in a vuejs webpack cli project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js

Hello there i used to vuejs cli to generate a project (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). The cli uses webpack and im having trouble using jquery inside of the vue files. Im always getting a.

```
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef  '$' is not defined
```

I have tried editing my webpack.dev.config to include the provide plugin block as follows:

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')

// add hot-reload related code to entry chunks
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: '#cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new FriendlyErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $ : "jquery",
      jQuery : "jquery"
    })
  ]
})
```

However when trying to use jquery i run into the same issues time and time again. Im not against using a cdn for this i really just cant get this think to include jquery no matter what i try.

If the vue file is helpful its i try to console.log $ like so inside the script block

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'how_can_we_help_you',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
console.log($)
</script>
```

Please help im very stuck and have been trying to fix this for quite a wile now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do u require jquery within Vue? Its considered a very bad practice to use jquery+ vue or jquery + angular.  whatever u can achieve in jquery, u should be able to write it in vue as well

Comment: @Plankton not really. some operations are way easier with jquery

Comment: You may find this link interesting: http://vuetips.com/bootstrap

Comment: @john Not usually. jQuery is just more familiar. The real issue with using jQuery is that it is generally used for dom manipulation, which is also being handled by `Vue`, so if you're not careful you can end up in a mess, which is why it's considered bad practice. If you are careful, it's fine.

Comment: @craig_h i know this. but there are _some parts_ that jquery handles better and and easier than vue can. What I'm saying is that instead of dispatching events through components and writing methods, you can simply use 1 line of jquery ---- given that you don't interfere with vue's rendered data. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say here

Comment: @john, actually not. Just because something is simpler (and u already know it) does not qualify the addition of a library into a production env. It just causes the bundling and loading process to be more cumbersome. its ok to dillydally on these as a curious developer, but unless its really unavoidable, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After two days of searching. Its eslintrc.js

add this to the following and it will fix the provide plugin.

```
env: {
  browser: true,
  jquery: true
},
```

Answer (score 7):

go into main.js and do

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

or

```
Vue.use({
    install: function(Vue, options){
        Vue.prototype.$jQuery = require('jquery'); // you'll have this.$jQuery anywhere in your vue project
    }
})
```

Comment: After being happy with complicated answers elsewhere on the Internet, it turns out that first simple one-liner was all that was needed to make it work. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for those who are not using webpack is using expose-loader:

```
yarn add expose-loader
```

and the in your main.js

```
import "expose-loader?$!jquery";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. I put my changes in webpack.dev.conf.js instead of webpack.dev.config and eslintrc.json instead of eslintrc.js.