# Can not include JQuery without npm in Vue JS project

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

I'm trying to import JQuery without using npm to my Vue JS project. Here's what I'm trying:

```
***jquery-functions.js***

import '../../public/js/jquery.min.js'      

export function bar(){ $(".foo"){...} }
/$ is not defined as function/
```

Comment: This is not how you import "stuff" in JS. Spend 5s on googling it.

Comment: welcome to JS modules. You need to `export function hello(x){ return x+5 }` in one file and need to `import { hello } from "a.js";` in the other file.

Comment: That's because `var` declares a module-level variable, not a global one.

Comment: hey hey calm down, I know this is not convention but I'm was trying to import a library that has already written without export statement. So I found this answer and it says that if variables are defined globally in that libraries I can use them like that. Here's the ref to link: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-a-third-party-library-js-without-export-in-my-component/23047

Comment: It **doesn't** define a variable globally.

Comment: *"So I found this answer and it says that if variables are defined globally in that libraries I can use them like that."* which is correct, but we're back to Bergi's comment that the variable is **not** defined globally.

Comment: Ok I've learned how to define a global window variable but to be honest I was trying to import an old version of JQuery.  So from that point it seems JQuery doesn't define a global variable. What I'm trying to do is just to include scripts back to back just like we do in index.html file so I want to be able to use it globally.

Comment: From the Vuejs tag I can see this is already likely a webpack misunderstanding. 

You can register libraries in vuejs via main.js setting the global variable or in jQueries instance you can set the env variable in eslintrc.js: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496906/how-to-include-jquery-in-a-vuejs-webpack-cli-project

Comment: @Tom'Blue'Piddock I think I'm getting closer but in the link you shared it uses JQuery as webpack plugin I'm trying to import it from my static files in public folder. Any idea about that one ?

Comment: If you can set it up with eslintrc.js instead then do this. Vuejs and Webpack are configurable to be able to leverage global access to things like jQuery so unless you have a serious requirement from this static jQuery file I would try switching to using your packager (webpack or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

`var hello` is evaluated in module scope, this prevents variables from leaking to global scope.

In order for a global to be defined, it should be assigned explicitly as such:

```
window.hello = function (x){x+5};
```

As for jQuery, it's specific to how the module works. It's UMD module and it isn't exposed as a global when jquery.min.js is imported as a module.

It should be assigned explicitly as a global either:

```
import jQuery from '../../public/js/jquery.min.js';

window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Or this can be done by means of Webpack that is used by Vue CLI internally, as [the answer in related question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52154045/3731501).

Comment: Ok I've learned how to define a global window variable but to be honest I was trying to import an old version of JQuery. So from that point it seems JQuery doesn't define a global variable. What I'm trying to do is just to include scripts back to back just like we do in index.html file so I want to be able to use it globally. How can I achieve that within a .vue file with JQuery ?

Comment: *What I'm trying to do is just to include scripts back to back just like we do in index.html* - this can mean that modules are misused. I'm not sure what your example has to do with jQuery, it isn't used there. Can you clarify this? Could probably be what this comment suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136714/javascript-imported-function-gives-funciton-undefined-error/57136879#comment100789406_57136714

Comment: I've updated the question. Basically I'm just trying to import JQuery from my static files without using npm.

Comment: This is a different case and is specific to jQuery. I updated the post. Since you want it to be a global, it may be easier to load jQuery with <script> instead of an import.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above but somehow I couldn't get it working. Either **eslint** was giving function not defined error for `$()` or bootstrap couldn't see the included jQuery. I don't know if it's ok to include jQuery globally but I found the solution by including jQuery to my **index.html** file with `<script>` tags. Then in my jquery-functions.js file I disabled **eslint** then everything was working just fine on run time.

```
***jquery-functions.js***
 /* eslint-disable */     

export function bar(){ $(".foo"){...} }
```

I did it like that so that I can separate jQuery methods from from Vue JS methods. It might be better to use **npm** to avoid including jQuery globally so that you can include it only in components that you need. For me I was concerned with compatibility of all other (6 of them) jQuery dependent libraries included in the template that I downloaded from internet.